# c# XML Serializing with derived classes using different namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, derived-class, xml-deserialization

I am trying to read a xml file and deserialize it to my InsertSensorType class and than read VALUE1,VALUE2 .. .I tried to add XmlElement name to my *InsertionMetadata* attribute in InsertSensorTypeMetadata class, but it doesn't work.I have searched and found solutions but they were not valid for this problem. Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Xml File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<swes:InsertSensor     
    xmlns:swes="http://www.opengis.net/swes/2.0"
    xmlns:sos="http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0" >
  <swes:metadata>
    <sos:SosInsertionMetadata>
      <sos:observationType>VALUE1</sos:observationType>
      <sos:observationType>VALUE2</sos:observationType>
      <sos:featureOfInterestType>VALUE3</sos:featureOfInterestType>
      <sos:featureOfInterestType>VALUE4</sos:featureOfInterestType>
    </sos:SosInsertionMetadata>
  </swes:metadata>
</swes:InsertSensor>
```

My Classes :

```
namespace Problem1.Classes
{
    [SerializableAttribute()]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/swes/2.0")]
    [XmlRootAttribute("InsertSensor", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/swes/2.0", IsNullable = false)]
    public class InsertSensorType
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("metadata")]
        public InsertSensorTypeMetadata[] metadata { get; set; }
    }

    [SerializableAttribute()]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/swes/2.0")]
    public class InsertSensorTypeMetadata
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SosInsertionMetadata", Type = typeof(SosInsertionMetadataType))]
        public InsertionMetadataType InsertionMetadata { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(SosInsertionMetadataType))]
    [SerializableAttribute()]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/swes/2.0")]
    public abstract partial class InsertionMetadataType
    {
    }

    [SerializableAttribute()]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0")]
    public partial class SosInsertionMetadataType : InsertionMetadataType
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("observationType", DataType = "anyURI")]
        public string[] observationType { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("featureOfInterestType", DataType = "anyURI")]
        public string[] featureOfInterestType { get; set; }
    }

}
```

And here is my main code :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlElement xmlRequest = null;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("request.xml");
            xmlRequest = doc.DocumentElement;
            executeRequest(xmlRequest);
        }

        static void executeRequest(XmlElement xmlRequest)
        {
            InsertSensorType insertSensorRequest = ValidateRequest<InsertSensorType>(xmlRequest);

            InsertSensorTypeMetadata[] _InsertSensorTypeMetadata = insertSensorRequest.metadata; 
            Console.WriteLine("Length of metadata :" + _InsertSensorTypeMetadata.Length);//1
            foreach (InsertSensorTypeMetadata istm in _InsertSensorTypeMetadata)
            {

                SosInsertionMetadataType sos = istm.InsertionMetadata as SosInsertionMetadataType;
                //sos is null

            }
            Console.Read();
        }

        static T ValidateRequest<T>(XmlElement xmlRequest) where T : class
        {
            string xml = xmlRequest.OuterXml;
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            //XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), new Type[] { typeof(SosInsertionMetadataType) });
            T typeInstance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            return typeInstance;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is that :

added this line to over InsertionMetadata attribute in InsertSensorTypeMetadata class

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "SosInsertionMetadata", Type = typeof(SosInsertionMetadataType), Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0")] // added
```

change my deserialize method

```
public static T ValidateRequest<T>(XmlElement element) where T : class
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(element));
}
```

and changed way to print values

```
static void executeRequest(XmlElement xmlRequest)
{
    InsertSensorType insertSensorRequest = ValidateRequest<InsertSensorType>(xmlRequest);
    foreach (InsertSensorTypeMetadata istm in insertSensorRequest.metadata)
    {
        SosInsertionMetadataType sos = (SosInsertionMetadataType)istm.InsertionMetadata;
        foreach(string s in sos.featureOfInterestType)
            Console.WriteLine(s);

        foreach (string s in sos.observationType)
            Console.WriteLine(s);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InsertSensorType insertSensorType = new InsertSensorType() {
                metadata = new Metadata() {
                    insertSensorTypeMetadata = new InsertSensorTypeMetadata() {
                        InsertionMetadata = new List<InsertionMetadataType>() {
                            new ObservationType() { value = "Value1"},
                            new ObservationType() { value = "Value2"},
                            new FeatureOfInterestType() { value = "Value3"},
                            new FeatureOfInterestType() { value = "Value4"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InsertSensorType));
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("swes","http://www.opengis.net/swes/2.0");
            ns.Add("sos","http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0");

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, insertSensorType, ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(InsertSensorType));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            InsertSensorType newInsertSensorType = (InsertSensorType)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "InsertSensor")]
    public class InsertSensorType
    {
        [XmlElement("metadata")]
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("metadata", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/swes/2.0")]
    public class Metadata
    {
        [XmlElement("SosInsertionMetadata")]
        public InsertSensorTypeMetadata insertSensorTypeMetadata { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("SosInsertionMetadata", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0")]
    public class InsertSensorTypeMetadata
    {
         [XmlElement()]
         public List<InsertionMetadataType> InsertionMetadata { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(ObservationType))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(FeatureOfInterestType))]
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0")]
    public class InsertionMetadataType
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "observationType", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0")]
    public class ObservationType : InsertionMetadataType
    {

    }
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "featureOfInterestType", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0")]
    public class FeatureOfInterestType : InsertionMetadataType
    {

    }
}
​
```

Comment: Hi @jdweng, thanks for your reply, I see you changed some classes and attributes, but i shouldnt change my classes they are generated with xsd.

Comment: then why does my code work and your code fails?  The automatic generated classes do not work for every situation.  They are just starting point and usually need to be edited.

Comment: Yes you are right, so i added         [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "SosInsertionMetadata", Type = typeof(SosInsertionMetadataType), Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/sos/2.0")] line to over InsertionMetadata attribute in InsertSensorTypeMetadata class. and changed my deserialize method, now its working. thanks again!